# PostgreSQL PqGetValue char to integer in c programming

Tags: c, postgresql, ubuntu, char, integer

I have a little problem with PostgreSQL results and integer in C language. So I have a simple table with this structure :

### ID(pk int) | name (text) |  values (int)

1          |  apple      |  100

2          |  banana     | 9

I use this code :

```
PGconn *conn = PQconnectdb("user=un password=pw dbname=db hostaddr=1.2.3.4 port=5432");
res = PQexec(conn, "SELECT * FROM fruits WHERE name='banana'");
int *banan_count;
banana_count = (int)PQgetvalue(res, 0, 2);
printf ("Banana values : %u\n", banana_count);
PQclear(res);
do_exit(conn);
```

The problem is that my results isn't '9' when I try print out with 'banana_count', but when I print out 'PQgetvalue(res, 0, 2)' then I got '9', so I think I have a conversion problem, but I can't find a solution. So my question is that how can I convert 'PQgetvalue(res, 0, 2)' to integer variable in C proramming language? (I use Ubuntu 18.04 and for compile my fruits.c with gcc).

Thank you for the supports and helps.

Comment: Look at [atoi](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi) function. `printf("%d\n", atoi(PQgetvalue(res,0,2)));`

Comment: Thank you for your quickly answer, I tried atoi but sadly its also not worked properly. In tomorrow I will try 'rb_cstr_to_inum' maybe it will working. :)

Comment: Well, it _should_ indeed work. If you show exactly what you have tried someone can spot the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C, text is technically an array of chars, followed with a null-term. Roughly, array is a pointer to allocated memory of known size (syntax may vary widely). So let's see the code.

```
PGconn *conn = PQconnectdb("user=un password=pw dbname=db hostaddr=1.2.3.4 port=5432");  //No doubts. It's your professional area.
res = PQexec(conn, "SELECT * FROM fruits WHERE name='banana'");  //same thing.
//int *banan_count; //Aside the typo (banana_count), you don't need a pointer to int! PQgetvalue returns a pointer to char (roughly equal to array of chars, roughly equal to text, you'll learn differences later). This array keeps ONE int value in text form.
int banana_count_2; //That's what you need: a single int value. Not a pointer.
//banana_count = (int)PQgetvalue(res, 0, 2); //Wrong: you take the pointer to char, convert it few times and assign to your int* pointer. Pointer becomes technically valid, but it points to first group of characters, reading them as an integer value (probably char1 + char2*256 + char3*65536 ... depending on your platform). Of course, actual integers are not represented in text form in computer memory, so you get an absurdly huge value (even '0' character has code 48).
banana_count_2 = atoi(PQgetvalue(res,0,2));  //PQgetvalue allocates memory by itself, so the char* it returns points to a valid, allocated memory area. We can say it's an array filled with null-terminated text line, and give this line to atoi();
printf ("Banana values : %u\n", banana_count_2);
PQclear(res);  //Good thing you didn't forget to unallocate the char array!
do_exit(conn);
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation :) its true I need learn lots, so thank you again.

Comment: Also, ```printf ("Banana values : %u\n", banana_count);``` printed the pointer itself (memory address), it's not depending on the value (it's a number of memory cell storing it). ```printf ("Banana values : %u\n", *banana_count);``` will print that "absurdly huge value". That's what I forgot to mention.

Comment: I see, thank you again, and its true, I've got lot of times a huge value.